# Is there any way to change the radius of specific corner of Material design CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-cardview, material-components-android

I am using material design in my android app and normally for changing the radius of the corner of card i use  **app:cardCornerRadius**, but this will change all the four corner of card. I want to change any specific corner of the card. I dont want to use drawable only for changing the corner. Is there any way through xml or programatically.

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a solution **but it requires v21 Lollipop and above**.
You can do it programmatically as follows:

In your activity class have `public static int radius = 20;`
and in your `Oncreate()`;

```
CardView card = findViewById(R.id.my_card);


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   makeCustomOutline(card);
}
```

then define the function as follows:

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void makeCustomOutline(CardView card){

    card.setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
        @Override
        public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {

            outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, view.getWidth(),
                    (view.getHeight() + radius), (float)radius );
        }
    });
    card.setClipToOutline(true);

}
```

by using the `setRoundRect()` method you can control which corner of the cardview gets the radius and which doesn't. The above code will make only the top corners rounded, bottom corners will not be rounded.

References:

[This answer was adapted from this article](https://medium.com/@iamsadesh/android-ui-creating-a-layout-rounded-only-in-the-top-d60514ccab77)

[docs on setRoundRect() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html#setRoundRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20float))

[docs on ViewOutlineProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOutlineProvider(android.view.ViewOutlineProvider))

Comment: outline.setRoundRect(0, 0-radius, view.getWidth(), (view.getHeight()), (float) radius); for bottom_left and bottom_right rounded corner.

Comment: youre the real mvp!

Answer (score 13):

With the version 1.1.0 of the Material Component you can [customize the shape](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) of your component using the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute.
You can use it in the view or in the style.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
      .....
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialCardView.Cut">
```

and then define your favorite shape:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialCardView.Cut" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">16dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

With the code you can apply a custom [`ShapeAppearanceModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/ShapeAppearanceModel) to the corner of the card using something like:

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.my_corner_radius);
cardView.setShapeAppearanceModel(
  cardView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
      .toBuilder()
      .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
      .setTopRightCornerSize(0)
      .build());
```

Comment: Great answer! I tried it programatically and it worked great, until I placed an imageView inside of the MaterialCardView. In this case, the corners get overlapped by the image, so it seems like the cardview has no corner radius... I need a way to change the corner radius programatically without this problem, any ideas?

Comment: @TiagoNunes try to use [`ShapeableImageView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59430153/2016562)

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work in my use case, as I have an horizontal recyclerview of images...

Comment: @TiagoNunes I have the same use case. Did you find any working solution in this case?

Comment: @SaketKumar I don't remember, sorry... But at this point you can just use Compose for this, and there will be no issues.

Comment: @TiagoNunes yeah I use compose but it's not fully migrated and still I have to use XML in this case. :(

Answer (score -1):

I am not pretty sure about Material design cardview to have that functionality or not. But I don't think that default cardview have that kind of functionality so on behalf of that material cardview you can use

**[This Library (click here)](https://github.com/captain-miao/OptionRoundCardview)**.

It is just my opinion may be there is another good solution for that.

Comment: Thanks for helping....but i think if there is no option then its good to use drawable instead of library..so might be i prefer drawable at last.

Comment: Yes, its up to you what you want to use.  I just suggest that.

Comment: @ManthanPatel the MaterialCardView has that kind of funtionality. No need of third party libraries

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Yes you are right. This answer I answered before material component came.