# ImageView with only bottom or top corners rounded

Tags: android, imageview, drawable, shapes, rounded-corners

I have answer on this question, but I spend too much time while searching for it.
That's why I created this question, so it would be easier for others.

You can't just round image corners with shape @drawable like usual View.
That's why you need to make some changes to Image inside code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248890/imageview-with-only-one-rounded-corner/59430153#59430153

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the another way to do this using Material Design **[ShapeableImageView](https://medium.com/android-beginners/shapeableimageview-material-components-for-android-cac6edac2c0d)**

Create one theme for shape and `cornerFamily`

```
<style name="ImageView.Corner" parent="">
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">8dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    </style>
```

Now add ShapeableImageView in XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
     android:layout_width="75dp"
     android:layout_height="75dp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/temp_product_image"
     app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ImageView.Corner"/>
```

I you want to full rounded ShapeableImageView:

```
<style name="ImageView.Round" parent="">
  <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

Full Rounded Output:

[image]

That's it Happy Coding :).

Comment: Where was your answer before?:)
This approach is better if you have material design.

Comment: I'm waiting for your question :P. Yes material design is good way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define shape firstly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Then use this shape as ImageView background:

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"

      android:background="@drawable/rounded"
      android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

And then in your activity write this code to add bottom rounded corners

```
img.outlineProvider = object : ViewOutlineProvider() {
    override fun getOutline(view: View?, outline: Outline?) {
            val corner = 48f
            outline?.setRoundRect(0, -corner.toInt(), view!!.width, view.height,corner)
        }
    }
img.clipToOutline = true
```

If you want top corners to be rounded use:

```
outline?.setRoundRect(0, 0, view!!.width, (view.height+48f).toInt(), 48f)
```

Comment: You can use `clipToOutline` only in API level 31 or higher